# How to change placeholder text of ion-input with type="date"

Tags: date, ionic-framework, input, capacitor

I'm trying to change the placeholder text of ion-input with type="date"
But it is not changing

**My Code:**

```
<ion-input
      inputmode="text"
      type="date"
      fill="outline"
      mode="md"
      placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY"/>
```

**Output:**

[image: Output]

I want to change placeholder text of ion-input with type="date"
Like it can be
"MM/DD/YYYY" or "Select Date Here"

Answer (score 0):

That’s how an input date looks like, the `mm/dd/yyyy` is not a placeholder but the default value.

But you should be able to style the input date with CSS, in example you can add `text-transform: uppercase` to the input and that should make the text uppercase.

Comment: I want to change placeholder text or default value as you are saying.  Could you tell me how it's possible?

Comment: For the default value use value=“01/01/2021” or the default date you want to use, it can only be a date, not text and no placeholder.